# json object in php not being read

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli

I want to pass `username` and `password` to a php script and check in the database. On the client side I use the following script to make a `json object` and post it to the php file.

```
var myobj = {};
myobj["usrname"]= $( "#customer option:selected" ).text();
myobj["usrpass"]= $("#psw").val();

var myjson = JSON.stringify(myobj);

$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "checkpass.php",
data: myjson
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

On the server side, when I see in `firebug`, the post is passed as

> Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedDo not sort
>   {"usrname":"XXXXXXX...
>   JSON
>
> usrname
>       "XX"
>
> usrpass
>       "justdoit"
>   Source
>   {"usrname":"XXX","usrpass":"justdoit"}

however when i run the php script to check the query the it returns an error

```
$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$usrpass = $_POST['usrpass'];

$sql = "select count(*) from glusers where EmpName='$usrname' and EmpPass='$usrpass'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result >0){
$output = 'Success';
} else
{
$output = 'fail';
}
```

I have tried through all the posts but cannot get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: there are no values in $usrname and $usrpass. Hence, the mysqli query executes but without any result.

Comment: for the incorrect password also it returns a success output on execution of the script

Comment: please post the output of `console.log(myjson);`

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  log() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in <b>/home/arjunmb/airtec-intl.com/checkpass.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
Success

Comment: In your database, you have specified usrname to be a double, so it trows an error because what you are trying to insert is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Echo and die the statement in order for ajax to have a success event

> Js File

```
 var myobj = {};

        myobj["usrname"] = 'myUsername';

        myobj["usrpass"] = 'myPassword';



        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "url",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {post_data: myobj},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData);
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

> PHP action File

```
           /** if we print post we will get the following array * */
//print_r($_Post);
//die()
//Array
//(
//    [post_data] => Array
//        (
//            [usrname] => myUsername
//            [usrpass] => myPassword
//        )
//
//)

if (isset($_Post['post_data'])) {
    $myPost = $_Post['post_data'];
    $usrname = $myPost['usrname'];
    $usrpass = $myPost['usrpass'];

    $sql = "select count(*) from glusers where EmpName='$usrname' and EmpPass='$usrpass'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $num_row = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num_row > 0) {
        $output = 'Success';
    } else {
        $output = 'fail';
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    die();
}
```

Comment: did not work.  although i enter the wrong password it still returns $output as success.

Comment: But `$result`, doesn't contain the actual number of count, if the query runs succesfull it wil return true, so $result=1 and is higher then 0, to get the count use `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: It will return success since when using $result we are checking if the query wa successfull if you want to count the returned number of rows check my edited answer

Comment: thanks. got that error. but still it persists as the json object is not being parsed for the correct inputs as well

Comment: are you passing the text field from a form, i edit my answer on how to pass the fields @ArjunBhandari

Comment: @ArjunBhandari am sure this will work. I have tested in my side :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This : 
in js file :

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

            // Create an object using an object literal.
            var ourObj = {};

            // Create a string member called "data" and give it a string.
            // Also create an array of simple object literals for our object.
            ourObj.data = "Some Data Points";
            ourObj.arPoints = [{'x':1, 'y': 2},{'x': 2.3, 'y': 3.3},{'x': -1, 'y': -4}];


            var savedata = JSON.stringify(ourObj)
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"Users.php",
                data: {"points" : JSON.stringify(ourObj)},
               success: function(data) {
                    // Do something with data that came back. 
                    alert(data);
               }

            })
        });
```

In PHP File :

```
if (isset($_POST["points"])) {
$points = json_decode($_POST["points"]);


echo "Data is: " . $points->data . "<br>";
echo "Point 1: " . $points->arPoints[0]->x . ", " . $points->arPoints[0]->y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myobj = '{
usrname:'+$( "#customer option:selected" ).text()+',
usrpass:'+$("#psw").val()+'
}';
```

or

```
var myobj = {};
myobj.usrname= $( "#customer option:selected" ).text();
myobj.usrpass= $("#psw").val();
```

Comment: same problem, whether i use the correct or incorrect password. also i amended this to be  $result = $result->num_rows and then checking if $result > 0

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library as follows,

```
var myobj = {};
myobj["usrname"]= $( "#customer option:selected" ).text();
myobj["usrpass"]= $("#psw").val();

var myjson = JSON2.stringify(myobj);

$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "checkpass.php",
 data: myjson
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( msg );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you php code is invalid because you pass json day not name value pair so you cant get it from $_POST['username']. You need to get the whole post data and decode it like this.

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Now $data is dictionary array of username and password. Also sanitize your data before passing to query to avoid sql injection.